# Por que no carga el Iframe de Twitch en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy cargando el iframe de twitch de manera local, y no tengo problemas; el problema ocurre cuando le pongo en un dominio en http (no es https), el navegador me muestra el siguiente mensaje (To protect your security, player.twitch.tv will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.), alguna informacion, por fa.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, para que puedas obtener ayuda, deberías añadir el código que tienes hasta ahora usando el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/455289/edit), además te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: por cuestiones de seguridad se bloquea el iframe de origen https al cargarse desde una pagina en http, podes obtener un certificado para tu dominio via [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) o usando [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) el embed de twitch no tiene esas restricciones para ips "127.0.0.1/8" o "localhost" ( cualquier alias onda midev.local, miweb.test necesita ssl )

Comment: muchas gracias @aloMalbarez